# Request to review answers on the 'names' question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Stumped: What would replace 'names' in an alternate history?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/77849/stumped-what-would-replace-names-in-an-alternate-history)

This question now has 30+ answers (a couple have been deleted), which means the odds are that only the top few have been viewed by most of the people looking at the question. Can we ask that some members of the community to take a few minutes to look through all the answers to this question (not just the top few) and up/down vote or flag as appropriate please?

Comment: Can we close the question while we're at it? It's idea generation and too broad.

Comment: @sphennings I see it already has a close vote. I think it's definitely in the "potential close" grey area, but the actual requirements as given are pretty specific. Having said that 30 answers does suggest too broad...but many of those 30 are just rehashing each other's ideas.

Comment: @sphennings It's not too broad because the requirements are plainly stated, it is world building in that it relates to a society and not individuals in the society, and all questions are idea generation at some level. If I didn't need an idea I wouldn't ask the question because I'd already know.